# How to display an HTML page according to a certain value in a text file being 1 or 0

Tags: php, html, embedded, iot

I am an Embedded Software Engineer, with no familiarity with web development.
I am building a project where I have a flame sensor connected to a microcontroller. The operation is that when the sensor detects a fire, it writes the value 1 on a text file on the server using the PUT method through the ESP8266, and the website is infinitely monitoring the value written to the text file on the server, it displays a "No Fire" HTML page if the value is 0 and displays a "Fire Detected!" HTML page if the value is 1.

I built the index.html homepage successfully, but I cannot develop the PHP code or the other web development stuff correctly. All my trials give no useful result, I searched many times but I cannot figure out how to handle it.

This is my index.html

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <head>
        <title>
        Fire Detection System
        </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>
        <br>
        <font face = "Verdana" size = "5">Welcome to my Fire Detection System</font><br />
        
        </h1>
        
        
        <font face = "Arial">
        
        <br>
        <h4 style="line-height:19px;">
        This is an IOT project consisting of two sides:
    
        <br>
        <br>1) On the embedded side, I have a fire detector system based on STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller
        <br>2) On the web side, I have a website that you are viewing right now &#128513;
        </font>
        </h4>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        
        You can find the project details and the source code on this GitHub
        <a href="https://github.com/AhmedHeshamMostafa/Fire-Detector.git"> Repository </a>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <p style="font-family:'Courier New'">Designed and developed by
        <br>        
        Ahmed Hesham Mostafa 
        <br>
        Embedded Software Engineer</p>
        <p style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">ahmed.hesham.mostafa7@gmail.com</p>
        <br>
        <p>
        <a href="https://github.com/AhmedHeshamMostafa/"><img src="GitHub Logo.png"
        width="60" 
        height="60"</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ahmedhesham285/"><img src="LinkedIn Logo.png"
        width="60" 
        height="60"</a>
        </p>
        
        
    </body>

</html>
```

This is the monitor.html file

```
    <html>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <head>
        <title>
        No Fire
        </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>
        <br>
        <font face = "Arial" size = "5">Now you are monitoring the fire detection system</font><br />
        
        </h1>

</html>
```

This is my Backbone.php file

```
    <?php

while(1)
{
    lines = file('file.txt');
    $line_number = 0;
    

    if(($lines[0] == 1))
    {
        header("FirePage.html");
    }


    else
    {
        header("NoFirePage.html");
    }
}
```

I cannot think as a web developer. I intend that after displaying the monitor.html page, the website displays whether FirePage.html or NoFirePage.html according to the value in the text file.

Comment: What is `/lines` ??

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.

Comment: /lines was a mistake that I just corrected.